# jQuery add method to object, then trigger event on it

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events, dynamic-function

Consider following situation:
I have a jQuery Object, `$wrapper = $(this);`. This happens in a init call, like this `$('#unique-wrapper-id').initWrapper()'`. As you can already imagine `initWrapper()` is a function in `jQuery.fn`.

Now, still in the `initWrapper()` call I add a function to `$wrapper` like this

`$wrapper.getValue = function() { /* typical wrapper function */}`

and then, in a callback which is executed upon clicking on an element within the wrapper I call `$wrapper.trigger('change')`.
On the other end I listen to the regular jQuery change event and here's where it doesn't work out anymore.

```
$('#unique-wrapper-id').change(function() {
    var $wrapper = $(this);
    $wrapper.getValue(); // $wrapper.getValue() is not a function
});
```

Ok, so somewhere in the jQuery change event process `getValue()` gets lost. No problem, I'll just attach it to the DOMElement itself in the init call with

`$wrapper[0].getValue = function { /* typical wrapper function */ }`

This works as expected and I can execute the `getValue()` method on the DOMElement behind the jQuery Object on the listening end.

However, there are two things that bug me:

- Why does `getValue()` on the jQuery object get lost during the change event process?
- Why doesn't the jQuery constructor (`var $wrapper = $(this);`) copy the `getValue()` function of the DOMElement into the jQuery Object?

Comment: Every time you call `$(element)` it creates a **new** jQuery object that wraps the DOM element. So properties you added to the original jQuery object are lost.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. If `$wrapper` : `$('#unique-wrapper-id')` is defined before `.change()` event, should be able to use `$wrapper` within handler without calling `jQuery()` again. Could also possibly adjust to event delegation `$(document).on("change", '#unique-wrapper-id')` or `$wrapper.change(handler)` then `$(this).data().getValue()` inside of `handler`

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But it doesn't scale to multiple elements.

Comment: @Barmar weeell... that sorta makes sense :/ should have thought of that.

Comment: @guest271314 it is defined before the change event, but in a different function context. Could you elaborate the other approach with event delegation a bit more?

Comment: Event delegation is unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$wrapper` is the same element you should be able to store `getValue` within `.data()`

```
var getValue = function() { /* typical wrapper function */};
$wrapper.data("getValue", getValue);
```

---

```
$("#unique-wrapper-id").change(function() {
    var $wrapper = $(this);
    $wrapper.data().getValue();
});
```

Comment: thanks, I'll try that tomorrow, however that is just as intuitive to me as the workaround with adding the function to the DomElement.. but good poing, completely forgot about data.